# Regular expression to get last separator character before certain pattern

Tags: regex

What is the regular expression to get the position of the last separator character before a certain pattern?

For example, I have a string as follows

```
some value;some other value;some special XYZ value;some more special XYZ value
```

Here, the separator character is semicolon (";") and the pattern I am looking for is any string that contains "XYZ".

The correct answer is this case is position 28, which is the last occurence of the separator character (";") before an element containing the match pattern ("XYZ").

What would the regular expression look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;(?=[^;]*XYZ)
```

matches a semicolon that's followed by `XYZ` within the same segment of the string.

Use it once to find the first occurrence. If you use it repeatedly, you'll find the following occurrences, too.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regular expression

```
^.*(;).*XYZ.*$
```

`.*(;).*XYZ.*` would match greedily i.e. it would match till the last occurance of `;` having `XYZ` followed by it

Comment: That expression doesn't get the first `XYZ` but the second one.

Comment: @Howard thts what the op asked for i.e  the last occurance of ; which follows XYZ

Comment: Not really. OP says the semicolon in position 28 should match. The question *is*  worded unclearly, though.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Correct, I'm looking for the last occurence of the separator before (ie preceding) the match pattern (XYZ). Which is position 28 in the example given.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two steps:

- extract the largest substring containing the first occurrence of XYZ preceded by a separator
- in that substring find the position of the last separator

i.e.,

```
s = "some value;some other value;some special XYZ value;some more special XYZ value"
s1 = re.findall("^.*?;.*?XYZ",s)[0]
len(re.findall("(.*;)",s1)[0]) --> 28
```